# Is it really not valid to use setDataSource on the main thread?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I recently noticed that I'm getting reports of the following crash in my Android Developer Console:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
at java.net.InetAddress.getHostByAddrImpl(InetAddress.java:440)
at java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:313)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.checkHostdata(MediaPlayer.java:869)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.isLocalhost(MediaPlayer.java:940)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSourceBase(MediaPlayer.java:980)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1085)
[the rest is irrelevant]
```

It seems that somewhere in the [MediaPlayer.setDataSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29) method there is some code that touches the network which is causing StrictMode to bark. Which is a bit surprising as calling setDataSource on the main thread seems to be common practice.

So my question is, what's the best way to go about dealing with this issue? Should I move the mediaPlayer out of the main thread? Should I ignore it? Or, something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, strategically, this feels like a somewhat over-aggressive bit of `StrictMode` logic, one that perhaps could get fixed in the future, if `getHostByAddrImpl()` really isn't at risk of doing a blocking network I/O call.

Tactically, you should move the `setDataSource()` call to a background thread, particularly when the source is pointing at the network (`http`, `rtsp`, etc.).

Comment: But why is this happening in production?

Comment: @yydi: Because you are calling `setDataSource()` on the main application thread, apparently. `StrictMode` is set up on newer Android versions to complain about this automatically.

Comment: True. But even VideoView (looked at the source) calls setDataSource on the UI thread. It seems very strange that Android would break so many hundreds of apps...

Comment: @yydl: Well, there's no question that `getHostByAddrImpl()` has the `StrictMode` check, as you can see that in the source code as well. However, checking the `MediaPlayer` source, I do not see `setDataSourceBase()`. It is possible that this issue is peculiar to some device manufacturer's (or ROM modder's) changes to `MediaPlayer`. Are there any commonalities in the crash logs, in terms of the devices that are failing?

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be getting any device info along with the reports. But seeing that `setDataSourceBase` doesn't exist is a great find. Thanks!